# Size difference between python generated csv and converted xlsx file

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, openoffice-calc

I wrote a `python` program to rename file names (around 500k files) in a specific format. To track the status, I have created an array of array `status [[]]` to which I am appending filename, file path, status (whether renaming is successful or not) and error (if any). Once the process is completed, exporting that array to a `csv` using `pandas`.

```
status_file = # path to csv file
status_file_stream = open(status_file, 'w')

df_status = pandas.DataFrame(status)
df_status.to_csv(status_file, index=False)
```

Generated `CSV` file size is `228 MB`, but when I open it with `openoffice` application and save as `xlsx` then the new `xlsx` file size is only `15.6 MB` without loosing any data.

Why there is a huge size difference between `CSV` and `XSLX` or is this is the issue with `pandas` to get large file size?

Comment: compression! `csv` is just a fancy way to say this is a `txt` with commas, its a plain text file. `xlsx` on the other hand is a binary format and programs that generate that format compress the data, if your data is mostly the same, which im assuming it is because the paths are mostly the same, then its highley compressible, which is what you are seeing

Comment: @Nullman OP says CSV is 228mb and xlsx is 15 mb, so it doesn't make sense what you are saying

Comment: most of OPs data is identical(the paths), that would be extremely compressible

Comment: @Adelin i just tested it. i made a ~110 meg file containing same path with different file names, i then compressed it using zlib and it went down to around ~20 megs, this is without any sort of interesting optimizations that xlsx can handle

Comment: Oh, right, looks like the answer to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for completeness sake ill write my comment as an answer:

compression! csv is just a fancy way to say this is a txt with commas, its a plain text file. 
xlsx on the other hand is a binary format and programs that generate that format compress the data, if your data is mostly the same, which I'm assuming it is because the paths are mostly the same, then its highly compressible, which is what you are seeing

xlsx uses zip (at least according to google)

to test this claim I have generated a ~110MB file containing random file names with the same path and used `zlib` to compress it and the output was ~20MB

xlsx probably has additional optimizations but I did not dig into the format

Comment: _"xlsx uses zip (at least according to google)"_ — please try the following ① copy `file.xlsx` to `file.zip` ② double click `file.zip`

Comment: thats pretty fancy, i thought it would have internal zipped parts

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue and was nt sure why the difference is in sizes,

issues could be because of :

1. xlsx compresses the files so it will be smaller than csv's
2. if a column has only integers then xlsx considers it as Int64 and csv considers it as float64